# Saving and displaying images in SQLite

Tags: android, image, android-sqlite

First note is code works just fine with lower quality images, however when a user uses an image that they took with their phone camera at higher quality the image dose not show up  in the application. Lower quality images do however. Can someone please explain why this is happening and the best way to code a fix for this?

ImageDatabaseHandler.java (relevant code only)

```
public Boolean deleteItem(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String table = "images";
    String whereClause = "id=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
    return true;
}

public Boolean insertimage(String x, Integer i) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(x);       
        byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.available()];
        fs.read(imgbyte);
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("id", i);
        contentValues.put("img", imgbyte);
        db.insert("images", null, contentValues);
        fs.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public Bitmap getimage(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Bitmap bt = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from images where id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        byte[] imag = cursor.getBlob(1);
        bt = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imag, 0, imag.length);

    }
    return bt;
}
```

MyActivity (relevant code only)

```
int stockNumber = 0;

Button insert, delImg;
EditText number;
ImageView imageView;
ImageDatabaseHandler db;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
insert = findViewById(R.id.SetImage);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    db = new ImageDatabaseHandler(this);
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse(
                    "content://media/internal/images/media"
            ));
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    delImg = findViewById(R.id.delImageButton);
    delImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startImageRemove();
        }
    });
}


protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    try {
        if (db.getimage(stockNumber) != null) {
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(db.getimage(stockNumber));

imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(db.getimage(stockNumber), 500, 500, false));
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal database error!\nset new 
image and try again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String x = getPath(uri);

        db.deleteItem(stockNumber);
        finish();

        if (db.insertimage(x, stockNumber)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if (uri == null) return null;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

I was thinking on a way to compress an image once its chosen from the media store on the device before adding it into the database however I'm still relatively new to programming and Android Studio, any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated as always :)

Comment: Check the size of the bite array right before inserting the images.  Your probably going over the blob or string limits.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html   Blob and string limits are first in this list.

Comment: Picasso is probably the best image handling library for Android,   See this other answer on how easily you can resize images with it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286239/2912185

Answer (score 0):

SqlLite has limits for Types, in your case its probably a BLOB type. You can read more about these limits here: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

A safer way of Implementing this is to Store the path to the Image in your Database rather than the complete Bitmap. If you do not wish to keep the original filepath you can copy the image first to your Applications Internal Filespace and than store that new copied Images location in your Database. You can read more about the Filespace here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#filesInternal

Comment: Additionally I would like to point you to Room (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) for using your Database as it will make your live easier

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by having the application launch the camera app itself and set the quality of the image that way. See below for code;

ImageDatabaseHandler.java (relevant code only)

```
public Boolean insertimage(byte[] x, Integer i) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("id", i);
    contentValues.put("img", x);
    db.insert("images", null, contentValues);

    return true;
}
```

myActivity.java (relevant code only)

```
 ....
    insert = findViewById(R.id.SetImage);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    db = new ImageDatabaseHandler(this);
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(QuickReferenceListItem.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        RequestCameraPermissionID);
                return;
            }
            startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, requestCode);
        }
    });

 ....

 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, 
 @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestCameraPermissionID: {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA) 
!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                insert = findViewById(R.id.SetImage);
                imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                requestCode = 20;

                Intent photoCaptureIntent = new 
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, requestCode);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

....

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

         db.deleteItem(stockNumber);
         finish();

         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
         byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();


         if (db.insertimage(b, stockNumber)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Successful", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
       }
   }
```